# MVC model and SQL table name are the same

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, zend-framework, model

My model is called Application_Model_Poll. Zend is forcing me name my database table the same as the model. Is there anyway I can just call the table Poll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Poll extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'Poll';
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have done anything other than add a protected member to the class? Do I have to use this anywhere?

Comment: My bad. I had it in the controller rather than the model.

Thanks